# MariaDB Can't Create New User

Tags: mariadb

Fresh install of MariDB 10.4 (fedora 31). I login into mysql as root:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select User, Host,Password from user;
+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| User  | Host      | Password                                  |
+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root  | localhost | *A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF |
| mysql | localhost | invalid                                   |
+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]
```

If I try to create a new user:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> create user 'developer'@'localhost' identified by 'pippo';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'developer'@'localhost'
```

As stated from the first table, the user `developer` doesn't exist.
The permissions of root seem fine:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTs;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password OR unix_socket WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: maybe the user already exists, or you don't have the privileges to create one?

Comment: @lainatnavi No, the user doesn't exist and I am root.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/cannot-create-user-account/

Comment: grants are ok. BTW, I moved the question to ServerFault.

Comment: Found the solution.
Documented [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003130/mariadb-cant-create-new-user/1003133#1003133)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of [MariaDB Can't Create New User](https://serverfault.com/q/1003130/145804) (Server Fault) and has a much better answer there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that although the user was not listed in `mysql.user` table, there was an entry in `mysql.db` with that user.

So the solution is: check also `mysql.db` for colliding usernames.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the DB that is 'use'd when creating a new user does NOT get the user added to that DB but gets added to the mysql DB. Did it 2 times to me and I cannot add a new user to the selected DB.
as of this moment I have not figured out why.